# How to upload picture into a database with a html form which have a type = "file"?

Tags: phpmyadmin, blob, image-uploading, forms, http-post

I don't really know how to store my pictures in a database. The user will select a file, upload it, and cick to submit button. After it the picture should autimatically be loaded up into the database. Any trivial way to solve it? Should i use BLOB? It'd be more efficient if i could load up the picture into the server, and the sql variable would get the path of the picture. Is this implementable?

```
              <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
              <form method = "post" id= "myform" name="myform" action = "<?  php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
              <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
                 cellpadding = "2">


                    <td><input name = "user_name" type = "text" 
                       id = "user_name"></td>

                  <input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" 
                          value = "Küldés">
                 </tr>
               </form>



                    <td><form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />

                </form>
```

Comment: I think for small images you could use a base64 string,but for bigger images, upload the file and store it on the server, and then reference the filename in the database. If it's that what you want, I can post an answer (because I'm working on a code that has the same function, so I only need to copy+paste here)

Comment: I would really appreciate it. I'll only use small size pictures, but the essence of the system is to make it absolutely automatically. The user choose a file, and it should be uploaded into the server directly, and the sql variable should get the path to it automatically.

Comment: I hope it's that what you are looking for. - Answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just use:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
<input type="file" name="theimage" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**PHP:** (uploadpic.php)

```
<?php
$uid = uniqid();

$image = $uid . $_FILES['theimage']['name'];

//Make sure that the folder "images/" exists
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theimage']['tmp_name'],'images/' . $uid . $_FILES['theimage']['name']);

// Assuming you already have the row and you use a SESSION which stores your username
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE your_table SET image = '$image' WHERE username = $_SESSION['username']", $sqlconnection);
?>
```

If there's any question or errors, feel free to comment and I'll help you.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't use Session, so i don't know what should i substitute it with :S And i'm afraid of that the path will not be enough exact. public_html/images/clients <- This is the path where i want to upload the files.

Comment: Show me how your SQL query looks like (simplified) and maybe I can tell you with what you can replace that "username". Now to the path: If you want to upload the file to `public_html/images/clients`, just change it in the code above, it's easy.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));    $conn contains the 'hostname', 'username', 'password', 'databasename'. $sql contains the "Insert into...." command. Or is it too simple?

Comment: Oh i get it. I have an user_name variable, it will be ok. It's not working yet but you helped me a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Now it'll work for sure. Anything, just comment and I'll help you out

Comment: I changed the line:      $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET user_image = '$image' WHERE user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']", $sqlconnection);   but i have an errorr "syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? Sorry, yesterday I was offline since then...

Comment: Yes, i resolved it, and now i don't get any errorr, but it's still not working :S Essentially nothing happens. The picture i choose is not loaded up into the server :S I almost there, but i'm sure it must be a really tiny mistake i make.

Comment: Are you sure that you established the connection with the sql database? Are you sure that you are UPDATING the row? If the row doenst exist, UPDATE won't work. Use INSERT instead, If that's the case.

Comment: Progress! My database got the name of the picture. Unfortunately, the file hasn't been loaded up into the server, and the table variable 'user_image' just got the name of the picture.

Comment: The paths are correct? `move_uploaded_file` contains the right path?

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['theimage']['tmp_name'],'public_html/images/clients' . $uid . $_FILES['theimage']['name']);     I think it's OK. Any idea?

Comment: `$_FILES['theimage']` .... Are you sure that your submit form contains the `file` input with `name='theimage'`?

Comment: Do you say, this method only works if the chosen file name is = 'theimage' ? I don't really get it what the ['theimage'] and ['name'] parameters are doing.

Comment: The first [ ] is the name of the input and the second following [] is the parameters, in this case [name] to get the filename of the file.

Comment: Finally I managed to upload the file. I've got only one last problem. I'm using a form to send the data, but that form's action =  "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" So I tried to make a second form, in the first form, but it doesn't  load up the file. If i make the form outside the firts form, it's working :)

Comment: @JustMatthew Post the code in the question (Edit it) and I'll look at.